# How can I share the Internet on my laptop to my wireless network connection in my laptop?

Tags: networking

I set up the wireless network connection on my laptop, then, my local area connection is plugged in. But the wireless connection still has no network access. How can I share the internet in LAN to my wireless network connection? So that I can be able to use my wifi hotspot. Please reply as soon as possible! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ap-hotspot to create wifi hotspot..

To install use this command.

`sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot`

Then configure using

`sudo ap-hotspot configure`

And then start the hotspot

`sudo ap-hotspot start`

to stop

`sudo ap-hotspot stop`

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Settings > Network**, Click **Wireless**, and click the button at the bottom that says **Use as Hotspot...**